# Combining the text of two cells as output for a filepath

Tags: excel, vba, merge, range

Dear community of stackoverflow,

I've been working on a program that makes a map structure depending on the index made in Excel.

This index is variable, meaning that the names of the chapters can be different at all times. The number of chapters is not always the same. Because I used data validation to select what the chapter will be, I can't get the chapter to be numbered in that same cell using the concatenate option. See here:

[image: Image1]

Depending on the index I would like a folder structure of the index. I can get this to work for `C56` and `D56`. So that means one chapter. This is the code:

```
Sub Try_This_Maybe_Multiple()

    Dim myDir As String
    myDir = Sheets("Invulformulier").Range("J6") & "\" & "Material data book" & "\" & Sheets("Index").Range("C56") & " " & Sheets("Index").Range("D56")
    MkDir myDir
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Now I've tried to put in the `Range("C56:C70")` and `Range("D56:D70")`. (`C56` is where the index starts) Unfortunately that didn't work. I've also searched multiple sites and tried out different things. That didn't give any results too.

Short recap; I want to merge the text of cells `C56` and `D56` in the code. And then the same for `C57` and `D57`, etc.. without having to write it for each separate row.

The idea eventually is that a person will place pdf files in the folder structure where it belongs and then makes a combined pdf file as in the structure of the folder:

[image: Image2]

I hope my question is clear enough. If not please ask me what info is required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `For` loop to go through the cells in the range and create the folders based on the rows. Assuming your range of cells is separated by a row in between and runs from row 56 to 70, try this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim myDir As String
    Dim x as long

    For x = 56 to 70 Step 2
        myDir = Sheets("Invulformulier").Range("J6") & "\" & _
                "Material data book" & "\" & Sheets("Index").Range("C" & x) & " " & _
                Sheets("Index").Range("D" & x)
        MkDir myDir
    Next x    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx! That worked great. I was thinking of such a solution but didn't know how to set it up.

Comment: No problem, if you're satisfied with the response you can mark the answer as correct. Have a good day, J

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution for a "Run-time error '75': Path/File access error". This is probably because I entered "x = 56 to 80" while there is only data till cell 72.

Comment: Think I solved it myself. Simply added an "If" statement that if a cell is blank the "MkDir" won't do it's job.